# How to moving map under marker and get position like UBER app in FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

Ineed get posistion from fixed marker in map and move map under marker

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Stack` widget, which will have `GoogleMap` widget on top, and your marker centered in your screen.